# removing redundancy from dataset with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, redundancy

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
  0.03658  -0.02192  -0.01772   0.00612   0.01160   0.88852 type1
  0.03658  -0.02192  -0.01772   0.00612   0.01160   0.88859 type1
  0.03813  -0.01910  -0.02290   0.00906   0.01384   1.78929 type1
  0.04076  -0.02248  -0.02368   0.00903   0.01465   1.51693 type1
  0.04076  -0.02248  -0.02368   0.00903   0.01465   1.51720 type1
  0.04997  -0.04319  -0.02970   0.00945   0.02025   1.78306 type1
  0.05763   0.10729  -0.06824   0.04753   0.02071   1.72909 type1
  0.07291   0.13532  -0.08940   0.06161   0.02778   0.49674 type1
  0.04086  -0.03733  -0.02057   0.00562   0.01495   1.39900 type1
  0.05659  -0.01917  -0.04730   0.02125   0.02605   0.71228 type1
  ...
```

Each row contains measurements of 6 properties (first 6 columns) for various types of system (last column contains the type number).  At the moment there are 78 different systems which I need to characterize, but there is a problem, as you can see in the first two lines: they are identical except for the values for property 6, which are nearly the same anyway.  So I would like to remove lines of data if they are nearly the same-- but only within each class (ie., type number) and within some threshold value that I will specify.  I am new to sklearn, and I haven't found anything suitable by searching the docs, but is there a simple sklearn function to do this, or must I write my own linear algebra code to do it?

Comment: Is your data in a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an `sklearn` kind of thing. Just bin your data (according to the similarity threshold), and take unique data-points within each class.
That seems simple enough, right? Well, the only reason this is being turned into an answer instead of a comment, is to point out the following subtle but annoying point:
Similarity upto a threshold difference **is not transitive**. This means that you've either got an ill-defined (and maybe impossible) target in mind, or you're going to have a pain-in-the-neck dependency on the order of point in your data-set; two sides of the same coin really.
To exemplify, let's say we're looking at a single column's values, and we decide that a smaller than 2 difference is negligible, so that such points are to be considered "identical". Well what do you do with the following values for the first ten data-points?

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Every consecutive pair is "identical" so to speak, but you obviously don't want to group them all together!
I hope that makes sense to you, and I hope this is all of any help.
Good luck!

Comment: @sacul Yes, as a matter of fact, it is in a pandas DataFrame

Comment: I see your point.  Sequential elimination could reduce any number of data points down to one, but that isn't what I want to do.  I think this is just the usual problem of linear dependency, and removing a few samples, even if by an arbitrary criterion, should do the trick.  I just wanted a quick way of doing that within sklearn, since I'm already using that.  I want each class to be as fully represented by the 6 property values as possible, but duplicates, or near duplicates, don't really add any information, and might cause computational problems, so I have to remove them somehow.